# Defining document-level commands for existing symbols

Tags: expl3, xparse

I would like to define document-level macros for certain symbols with "meaningful" names. I wonder what the best way of doing this in a "clean" LaTeX3 package is.

**Option 1a:** Using `\def`

```
\def\EmptySet{\varnothing}
```

**Option 1b:** Using `\let`

```
\let\EmptySet\varnothing
```

**Option 2a:** Using `\NewDocumentCommand` directly

```
\NewDocumentCommand \EmptySet { } { \varnothing }
```

**Option 2b:** Using `\NewDocumentCommand` with deferred implementation

```
\NewDocumentCommand \EmptySet { } { \mathset_emptyset: }

\cs_new:Nn \mathset_emptyset:
{
  \varnothing
}
```

What is the recommended way of defining the macro in LaTeX3? Are there any subtile differences between them, e.g., with respect to spacing in math mode?

Comment: I'd use `\let\EmptySet\varnothing`

Comment: @Andrew I wouldn't. `;-)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There *are* subtle differences. Let's say your package is called `matthias.sty` and it has

```
\let\NotElement=\notin
```

(just a contrived example, but…).

Now let's try it.

```
\documentclass{article}

%% emulate here \usepackage{matthias}
\let\NotElement=\notin

%% another package follows
\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}

$x\NotElement X$ and $a\notin A$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Can you see the difference? There are other cases with `fourier` where symbols would become strange, this one is easy to obtain.

With `\let` you “freeze” the meaning at the moment of execution, but `fourier` *redefines* `\notin` to use a specific symbol, while the LaTeX kernel makes it by superimposing a slash to the “belongs to” symbol.

This wouldn't happen with `\newcommand{\NotElement}{\notin}`, because this just performs a replacement and uses the *current* definition of `\notin`.

Whether one should use `\NewDocumentCommand` is debatable. The main difference is that commands defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` are `\protected`, so they don't expand in write operations.

Comment: Is there any difference between option 2a and option 2b? The latter one would be preferred I guess if another LaTeX3 package had to make use of the macro.

Comment: @Matthias It would make sense to have “internal functions” and then user level commands.

Comment: +1 It's good to point out the distinction between `\let` and `\newcommand`. In situations like this I typically would use `\let` only *after* I have loaded all relevant packages. On the other, it is sometimes useful to  use `\let\NotElement=\notin`, for example, and then load another package because this gives you an easy way to access functionality that is otherwise "lost" when the package is loaded.

Comment: @Andrew yes a good rule is to always use \newcommand for alisases (when you want the new name to generate exactly the same as the old name at any point in your document) and use \let only for the situation that you really want to preserve the "current" meaning under a new name.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach With the current approach in latex2e amsmath to `\dots` some times you *do* need `\let` to make an alias and preserve the position of `\dots` :)

Comment: @Manuel sure, there *are* exceptions to the rule (should have said rule of thumb). Whenever a command depends on its exact number of expansions you can't place it into another expansion level (which is what \newcommand essentially does) without getting some failures, though what you say about \dots sounds to me as if Michael (or myself ages ago) implemented some shortcuts that aren't really good. Maybe you should make a minimal example and submit it as a bug report.